# .htaccess rewrite rule to remove extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So I have a .htaccess rewrite rule to remove the ".php" extension. It works. So now when a user goes to /page it shows /page.php. But is there any way to make it so that when a user goes to /page.php it'll show /page in the address bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ $1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Would this affect the POST method in any way? I'm having problems with it.

Comment: It definitely shouldn't. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The thing is that all the links on my pages are already set with a '.php' extension. So in my form, it action="sendcontactus.php". So I'm guessing what happens is that when this form submits, it performs the url rewrite to a link without the ".php" extension and the POST values get lost in the process.